# Count and Print number of rows with data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following PHP/Mysql query to print all data under **Email** column in **members** table

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM members";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row['Email']."<br/>";
}
```

**Output:**

name(1)@domain.com

name(2)@domain.com

.

.

.

name(n)@domain.com

How can i get output like below

**Required Output:**

1 name(1)@domain.com

2 name(2)@domain.com
.

.

.

n name(n)@domain.com

Where n= Number of rows in that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to show the number just use a counter.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$n = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $n . " " . $row['Email'] . "<br/>";
    $n++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace your code with this

```
$i=1;
$sql="SELECT * FROM members";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $i.'.'.$row['Email']."<br/>";
$i++;
}
```